# GDocs: Highlight Keywords in SelectedText

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to build a script that highlights pre-defined keywords within the selected text in a gdoc. The function is called upon a menu-buttonclick. 
I need to 
**1.** sift through the selected text, word by word, and compare them with the keywords.
**2.** access and manipulate word-attributes, such as fontcolor and fontstyle (bold etc..)

So far I managed to do **1.** (although in a pretty unhandy manner)

```
function highlightKeywords() 
{
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();

  if (selection) //not empty 
  {
    var elements = selection.getSelectedElements();

    // for each element (= text line)
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
    {
      var textLine = elements[i].getElement().asText().getText();
      var words = [];
      words = textLine.split(" ");

      //for each word...
        //for each keyword..
          //compare: word = keyword ?
    }

    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Highlighting keywords done!');
  } 
  else 
  {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Please select some text to be highlighted!');
  }
}
```

The Problem is **2.**, I don't know how to access and manipulate the attributes of a word in a gdoc.

What would be your approach to fulfill this task?

Answer (score 0):

For changing the attribute, bold for example, you would use the function setBold(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, bold) for the variable textline wich contains the result of "getText()"
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setBold(Integer,Integer,Boolean)

for this you just need the index of the word for the "startOffset" and the length of the word for the endOffsetInclusive

here you can find an example on how to get the index of every repetition of certain word in a string.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_lastindex.asp